# Autoloading class in Zend Framework 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework, autoload

I googled a lot articles about how to autoload class in Zend Framework. And most of them use the `Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource` or `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader` which I think is complicated.

I find a thread say a simple method to use the autoloading, just need edit the index.php and add a new resource method.

For example, I want the model class can be loaded automatically. I edit the code as below:

```
// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),***realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models')***
)));
```

And the resource method in Bootstrap.php:

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);

}
```

That's all.

So if I have a model named mymodel,it will be loaded automatically.
If a model in a folder like myfolder/mymodel, the class name need be changed as myfolder_mymodel.

So I think this style is so easy. But my question is that, why seldom people autoload like this?

Is there any shortcoming in this way?

Comment: What classes do you want to autoload usually in zend framework if we have library than you auto load those libraries using zend auto load namespaces(http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.examples.html). Are you looking to auto load the models or module files resides inside modules? Explain more.